# Why do functions with parameters not need (args) when called?

Tags: javascript, parameters

Why is it that when you do this:

```js
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
foo.addEventListener("keydown", foo);
function foo(e){
 console.log(e.keyCode);
}
```

Why do you not need this:

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
foo.addEventListener("keydown", foo(e));
function foo(e){
 console.log(e.keyCode);
}
```

But in some cases if you are passing something through parameter you would do this:

```js
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
foo.addEventListener("keydown", foo("Hello, world!"));
function foo(e){
 console.log(e);
}
```

WHY WHY WHY!!!

Comment: You need to use a different variable name for the function and for the DOM element. There is a huge difference between a function (object) and the return value you get from calling a function. Quite unrelated. Your question is littered by mistakes in the code blocks you provided.

Comment: THIS IS NOT A CALL TO A FUNCTION, this is an argument with the reference to a **listener function**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But in some cases if you are passing something through parameter you
> would do this:
>
> ```
> var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
> foo.addEventListener("keydown", foo("Hello, world!"));
>
> function foo(e){
>  console.log(e);
> }
> ```

**No, you wouldn't.** That would invoke `foo` with it's argument immediately and whatever the return value from calling it was (in your example, `undefined`), is what would then become the callback reference for the `keydown` event and `undefined` can't be a callback reference.

Let's see that in action. Below, `"Hello, world!"` is written to the console immediately and nothing happens when you key down in the input:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");
input.addEventListener("keydown", foo("Hello, world!"));
function foo(e){
 console.log(e);  // Immediately written to console!
}
```

```html
<input id="input">
```

### The second parameter for [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) takes a function ***reference***, which you can provide in several ways:

Supply the name (no parenthesis) of the function:

```
 .addEventListener("click", foo);
```

Supply an anonymous function (which doesn't invoke the function, just passes it):

```
 .addEventListener("click", function(){ // function body  });
```

Supply code to execute that returns a function (note the parenthesis here) which will invoke `foo` first and the return value from `foo`, which should be a function, will be the callback reference:

```
 function foo(){
   return function(){ console.log("Hello, world!");  };
 }

 .addEventListener("click", foo());  // foo is invoked first
```

But, as you can see, if you include the parenthesis, you are invoking the function right away, so if `foo` needs to be the function reference AND it takes arguments, you can't write this if `foo` doesn't return a function:
`.addEventListener("click", foo(arg));`

So, instead you have to wrap the function call in an anonymous function that we saw earlier:

```js
function foo(e){
 console.log(e);  
}
var input = document.getElementById("input");

// The anonymous function is the reference to execute when 
// the event is triggered. When that happens, the anonymous
// function will call foo with its arguments.
input.addEventListener("keydown", function(){ foo("Hello, world!"); });
```

```html
<input id="input">
```